# Comparison between two Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>> - Unconsistent behavior

Tags: rust, comparison, rc, refcell

I'm playing with `Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>` and came up with a behavior I don't understand.

Basically, in a struct, I own a collection of `Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>`. I can push an item of type `Concrete` implementing `Obj` in the collection, and get a `Rc<RefCell<Concrete>>` of it. Then I need functions to test whether a given `Rc<RefCell<Concrete>>` or a given `Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>` belongs to the collection (not the value, the refcell !).

I came up with the following [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8be7dff6b90a8a3b002bddcb7f3f135e) :

```
use std::{rc::Rc, cell::RefCell};

// Trait and implementing concrete type
pub trait Obj {}
struct Concrete {}
impl Obj for Concrete {}

// Structure owning a collection of Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>
struct V {
    v: Vec<Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>>
}

impl V {
    fn new() -> Self {
        V{v: Vec::new()}
    }

    // Push a an item in the collection and get a Rc<RefCell<T>> to manipulate it
    fn push<T: Obj + 'static>(&mut self, obj: T) -> Rc<RefCell<T>> {
        let obj = Rc::new(RefCell::new(obj));
        self.v.push(Rc::clone(&obj) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>);
        obj
    }
    
    // Check whether a Rc<RefCell<T:Obj>> is in the collection
    fn has_concrete_obj<T: Obj + 'static>(&self, candidate: &Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> bool {
        for obj in self.v.iter() {
            if Rc::ptr_eq(&obj, &(Rc::clone(candidate) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        false
    }

    // Check whether a Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>> is in the collection
    fn has_dyn_obj(&self, candidate: &Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>) -> bool {
        for obj in self.v.iter() {
            if Rc::ptr_eq(&obj, &candidate) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        false
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = V::new();
    let obj = v.push(Concrete{});
    // here, we could use obj with obj.borrow().fn_conrete() or obj.borrow_mut().fn_concrete_mut()

    // Basic tests that should pass
    assert!(v.has_concrete_obj(&obj));
    assert!(v.has_dyn_obj(&(Rc::clone(&obj) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>)));
    assert!(v.has_dyn_obj(v.v.iter().next().unwrap()));
}
```

It works as intended in the playground (all asserts pass), but not anymore when I run the exact same sample code on my computer : the second assert fails, whereas the first and the third pass. I don't get why, the first and the second doing basically pretty much the same thing...

Comment: Please include some information about the compiler you use  on your own machine (version, toolchain, ...).

Comment: Nitpick: why do you clone the `Rc`s?

Comment: @isaactfa I use rustc 1.64.0, installed on Windows11 from the [online installer](https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe)

Comment: @ChayimFriedman To perform the same operations as with the first assert using `has_concrete_type`. But anyway, a fourth `assert!(v.has_dyn_obj(&(obj as Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>)));` works in the playground but not on my machine

Comment: After some experimenting, it turns out that the tests pass when incremental compilation is turned on and fail when it's turned off. Now, I wouldn't necessarily assume that those tests should pass nor assert that they're basic. `Rc<RefCell<Concrete>> as Rc<RefCell<dyn Obj>>` actually seems like quite an involved process. After all, the new `Rc` can't actually be pointing at the original `RefCell`. It'll have to point at a trait object that in turn points at that `RefCell`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the investagation ! I understand, but then why the first assert with has_concrete_type passes but not the second ? How could I do differently to check whether something belongs to my collection ?

Comment: I genuinely have no clue why one passes and the other doesn't or how to fix it. I'm currently trying to come up with a smaller example of this to open an issue with.

Comment: @isaactfa Could it be that depending on the case rustc or llvm manages to devirtualise? Initially I was thinking ZST or marker trait (no method => no vtable) but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Oooh [`RefCell<dyn T>` is a DST, and `Rc<RefCell<dyn T>>` would be the trait object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222831/why-do-fat-pointers-sometimes-percolate-outwards) so the vtable pointer would be part of the Rc itself. Would explain why it's the exact same inner data.

Comment: @Masklinn Yeah, those were my thoughts too. I'm actually not sure which way I'd expect `Rc::ptr_eq` to behave in this case as there's no reason that it couldn't be holding two different wide pointers to the same `RefCell`. It's just so strange that it's sensitive to incremental compilation and, as I just found out, inlining `has_dyn_obj`. I've openend an issue, maybe someone more familiar with this has an idea what's going on under the hood https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/104446

Comment: @Masklinn Good catch, yeah, I reversed it in the comment. The issue is correct. Incremental compilation makes the test fail.

Comment: Looks like you need to inline `has_other` to get the last assert working, not `has_dyn_obj`. Which is weird because in my playground, the failed assert is with `has_dyn_obj` and not `has_obj`. Inlining my `has_dyn_obj` doesn't make the assert pass on my machine, even though inlining `has_other` with your code on my machine effectively makes the assert pass...

Comment: [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67109860/how-to-compare-trait-objects-within-an-arc) might help to understand better those behaviors